# Is it possible to zoom a projector image in software (Windows 7/8)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, projector

The projected image is just a little too big and the projector does not seem to have a good physical zoom.  I am looking for a way to shrink the image in the computer and output a slightly smaller image.

I have tried different resolutions on the projected desktop and the projection is always the same size. I do not know the model of the projector but it is relatively new and has a HDMI connection.

Comment: That's something you should be able to adjust on the projector itself.

Comment: A projector can usually be adjusted by moving the projector further behind, then refocus the image (making the projection bigger) And you may be able to adust the resolution in windows to a higher resolution.